# Style mapsforge map like google map or mapsme

Tags: android, google-maps, mapsforge

I'd like to know if there are existing rendertheme for mapsforge that would mimick GoogleMaps maps style, or even better mapsme (mapswithme) style ?

I'm currently using rendertheme-v4 which is not as nice looking and clear than the 2 other mentionned above.

If none exist how could we build one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of a mapsforge render theme copying the style of GoogleMaps, but by making changes to the osmarender theme included in the mapsforge [resources](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/tree/master/mapsforge-themes/src/main/resources/osmarender) you can style a map any way you want. With my own (very reduced) theme I highlight a number of buildings on a (very local) map. Here is just one tile from it:

[image]

[Here](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/docs/Rendertheme.md) you can get instructions on how to make those changes to your render theme.

Comment: Resources seams to have moved to https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/tree/master/mapsforge-themes/src/main/resources/osmarender

Comment: Okay, thanks. Just edited to original link accordingly.